# Quadruples in Array satisfying constraint

Tags: arrays, algorithm

In an array `A[1...n]` of positive integers, you are to count all quadruples in array satisfying:

```
A[i] + A[j] + A[k] = A[l] where 1 <= i < j < k < l <=n
```

I tried many things but could not come to a solution better than `O(n^3logn)`

Can we solve it in `O(n^3)` or `O(n^2)` satisfying the ordering constraint of indices?

Answer (score 4):

Why not `O(n^2)`? If we have

```
A[i] + A[j] + A[k] = A[l]
  where 1 ≤ i < j < k < l ≤ n
```

and we hashed all

```
A[i] + A[j] pairs
   where 1 ≤ i < j < n - 1
```

then we can iterate:

```
l = n
k = n - 1

check if A[l] - A[k] is in the hash
```

now update on each element as we descend:

```
j = n - 2

remove each instance of A[j] + A[i] in the hash
  where 1 ≤ i < j

for each instance of A[l] - A[j]
  where j < l < n
  check if a value exists in the hash

j = j - 1
...
```

Attempt in JavaScript:

```js
function f(A){
  if (A.length < 4)
    return 0;
  let n = A.length;
  let hash = {};
  let i = 0;
  let j;
  let k;
  let l;
  let sum;
  let diff;
  let count = 0;
  
  // Hash sums up to A[n - 3]
  // in O(n^2) time
  for (; i<n-3; i++){
    for (j=i+1; j<n-2; j++){
      sum = A[i] + A[j];
      hash[sum] = hash[sum] ? hash[sum] + 1 : 1;
    }
  }

  diff = A[n-1] - A[n-2];
  if (hash[diff])
    count = count + hash[diff];
  
  // Iterate on j descending,
  // updating the hash each time,
  // O(n) times
  for (; j>1; j--){
    // Remove instances of j in
    // the hash in O(n) time
    for (i=j-1; i>=0; i--){
      sum = A[i] + A[j];
      hash[sum] = hash[sum] - 1;
    }
    
    // Check for valid quadruples
    // in O(n) time
    // where the old j is now k
    k = j;
    for (l=k+1; l<n; l++){
      diff = A[l] - A[k];
      if (hash[diff])
        count = count + hash[diff];
    }
  }
  
  return count;
}

/*
1 1 1 1 3 3

x x x   x
x x x     x
x x   x x
x x   x   x
x   x x x
x   x x   x
  x x x x
  x x x   x
  
Total 8
*/
var A = [1,1,1,1,3,3];
console.log(JSON.stringify(A))
console.log(f(A));
```

Comment: Can you write full pseudo-code? I don't think it is O(n^2).

Comment: @SushilVerma sure, I added to the answer an attempt in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution in `O(n^2 + S)`, where `S` is count of quadruples satisfying your condition.

- Create a hash-based map `M` that maps integers to lists of pairs of integers (`HashMap<Integer, List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>>`).
- For each pair `(i, j)` of indices (`i < j`) add this pair to list `M[A[i] + A[j]]`. (For-loop by `j` should be outer and for-loop by `i` should be nested, so pairs in all lists are sorted by `j`)
- For each pair `(k, l)` of indices (`k < l`):

  - Let `L` be the list `M[A[l] - A[k]]`
  - For pairs `(i, j)` in `L`:

    - If `j < k`, add `(i, j, k, l)` to your answer
    - Else break nested loop, because pairs are sorted by `j` and following pairs will not satisfy condition `j < k`

Both outer loops run in `O(n^2)`, nested loop runs only `S` times through the whole algorithm, so time complexity is `O(n^2 + S)`.

Comment: Is there an upper bound we can place on S?

Comment: @גלעדברקן S should be O(n^4) in the worst case; e.g. take an array where the first half is all 1s and the second half is all 3s. There are `(n/2) choose 3` ~ O(n^3) triples of 1s to choose, and `n/2` 3s to choose, so the product of those is O(n^4).